# Converting From String

Tags: c#, string

```
string Audit = cmbToDoList.SelectedItem.ToString();
string _TransactionId = Audit;
cAuditTasksEntity transaction = _TransactionId as cAuditTasksEntity;
string trans = Convert.ToString(transaction);

sp.GetTransactionInfo(trans);

string result = (from cAuditTasksEntity transactionid in _TransactionId
                 select transactionid.TransactionId).ToString();
```

The section i am getting the error is: `_TransactionId as cAuditTasksEntity;`

It is saying that `Cannot convert type 'String' to 'DAL.cAuditTasksEntity via a reference conversion, boxing conversion,unboxing conversion,wrapping conversion, or null type conversion`

EDIT:

This is my class that you may need to know?

```
[Table(Name = "Audit_Tasks")]
public class cAuditTasksEntity
{

    private int _TaskId;
    private int _AuditUserId;
    private string _TransactionId;
    private string _TaskTypeId;
    private DateTime _Date;
    private string _AuditStatus;


    [Column(DbType = "INT", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int TaskId
    {
        get { return _TaskId; }
        set { _TaskId = value; }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "INT")]
    public int AuditUserId
    {
        get { return _AuditUserId; }
        set { _AuditUserId = value; }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "CHAR(32)")]
    public string TransactionId
    {
        get { return _TransactionId; }
        set { _TransactionId = value; }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "CHAR(32)")]
    public string TaskTypeId
    {
        get { return _TaskTypeId; }
        set { _TaskTypeId = value; }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "DATETIME")]
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return _Date; }
        set { _Date = value; }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "VARCHAR(255)")]
    public string AuditStatus
    {
        get { return _AuditStatus; }
        set { _AuditStatus = value; }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is; I have `taskId` that shows up in a combobox, when a user selects a task it needs to redirect them to another screen `xamlNewAudit.xaml` where the details of that transaction shows up automatically.

There is a `TaskTable' this hold`TaskId`and`TransactionId`

then when they get redirected I need to search the `TransactionTable` this will shows `Date creation` and other columns.

Comment: how would you like it to work? You are converting string to entity ...

Comment: @wudzik I just want it to convert but i am unsure how? basically from the `cmbToDoList` it shows a `TaskId` i want to get the `TransactionId` from the `TaskId` they selected?

Comment: And from where should the computer know how to convert a string to your object? The Pc's can't read your thoughts

Comment: @RononDex The line below it?

Comment: What is with the line below it?

Comment: @RononDex Converting the object above it to a string?

Comment: So? I still don't get where you are going with this... And your english is pretty hard to understand...

Comment: String is _not_ convertible to everything implicitly.

Comment: How do you fill `cmbToDoList`? There are several solutions and best for you depends on this question. Btw, your naming style is terrible, try to improve it ASAP. =D

Comment: @RononDex My SP needs to be passed a string, so I need to convert transaction into a string. I have done that by adding the line `string trans = Convert.ToString(transaction);` which works fine, but the line of code above it doesn't work.

Comment: @Sinatr My bad I'm an apprentice seeking help but other people don't understand that sorry. I fill `cmbToDoList` by searching a table called `cAuditTasksEntity` and bringing back all the tasks with their `userId` next to it.

Comment: what is a SP? So you are assuming that the pc knows how to the reverse action of something works? If you destroy something into 1000000 pieces, can you reverse that action? Do you think the pc's knows how to reverse something out of no-where? You have to parse the string on your **own** and create the object out of it

Comment: @RononDex Stored Procedure. That is why I am asking how can get around the problem.

Comment: Then you will have to show us how your string looks like

Comment: HungarianNotation... please stop doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest (probably) way to get `cAuditTaskEntity transaction`, which was selected by the user, is to create an array (or list, or dictionary, or whatever) to bind combobox displayed value to `cAuditTaskEntity` (via index).

Here is an example (it may be unusable by you, but should give an idea):

```
class cAuditTaskEntity
{
    public int A;
    public string B;
    ...

    public cAuditTaksEntity() {}
}

// data to fill into a combobox
cAuditTaskEntity[] data = new cAuditTaksEntity[] {new cAuditTaskEntity(), new cAuditTaksEntity(), new cAuditTaskEntity() ... }

// fill combobox, we represent data as a string
for(int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    cmbToDoList.Items.Add(string.Format("Item {0}: {1}, {2}", i, data[i].A, data[i].B));

// reading selected data
// we can't convert represented by a string data back, but we can take it by index from created earlier array
cAuditTasksEntity transaction = data[cmbToDoList.SelectedIndex];
```

---

### Update

You can override `ToString()` in your cAuditTaskEntity, so then you can add `object` directly and get them. Here is an example (create new solution, add combobox and button on a form):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public class A
    {
        public string B;
        public int C;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return B;
        }
    }

    A[] _a = new A[] { new A() { B = "1", C = 111 }, new A() { B = "2", C = 222 }, new A() { B = "3", C = 333 } };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (A item in _a)
            comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var a = comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex] as A;
        if (a != null)
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} {1}", a.B, a.C));
    }
}
```

In any case you cannot convert `string` -> `cAuditTaskEntity`, but you can utilize combobox `SelectedIndex` to find in the array of its `Items` selected one.

Comment: Thanks for the code, i have edited my question with my `cAuditTasksEntity` and also a little description. I have the data in the Combobox already, I just need to when i select the `TaskId` from that Combobox to get all the information about that `TransactionId`

Comment: Thanks for your code, im going to try and use it to make mine work just need to think what goes where. Thanks for your support and help.